# Issue while convert integer to base 10 string

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert base16 string to base10 string, below is my code:

```
unsigned int number = 0;

std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << "FF";
ss >> number;

std::cout << "number = " << number << "\n";
ss << number;
std::string out_string(ss.str());

std::cout << "out_string = " << out_string << "\n";
```

Here is my output:

> number = 255
>
> out_string = FF

I wish I get :

> out_string = 255

I am using C++98 compiler, can you explain and advise me how to do this ? Thank you.

Comment: `ss << number;` `std::hex` is still set

Comment: what should I do to reset to std::dec ?

Comment: You should use `std::dec`

Comment: I used, but still the same, or can you share with me where you use std::dec ? thanks

Comment: `std::cout<<std::dec<<"number="<<number;`

Comment: @Wander3r, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you do:

```
ss >> number;
```

The following things are true:

- The formatting flag `hex` is set inside `ss`.
- The stream error state flag `eofbit` is set inside `ss`, because you read all characters from the stream.
- There is `FF` stored inside `ss`.

If you want to write *new* content to `stream`, you have to clear it first. So:

- Clear the `hex` flag, set `dec` flag.
- Clear the `eofbit` flag.
- Clear the content of the `stringstream`.

In between:

```
std::cout << "number = " << number << "\n";
// here
ss << number;
```

add:

```
ss << std::dec;  // clearer then ss.setf(std::ios_base::hex, std::ios_base::basefield);
ss.clear();
ss.str("");      // or maybe ss = std::move(std::stringstream());
```